# Raphael js toFront() method distorted

Tags: javascript, svg, dictionary, raphael

I am just experimenting with with raphael.js to generate interactive svg map, well waht I wanted to achieve is somewhat like this example with indian map , that I downloaded from wikimedia , [JS fiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/allankiezel/FJrNN/)   , well everything is going well , but I am not able to figure out why "to.front()" is making the map distorted when I hover any state. Is it because of faulty SVg or has something to do with my codes

[MY problamatic fiddle , distorted on hover](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/3sDDM/)

Well here is my little bit of code

```
regions[i].mouseover(function (e) {
        this.node.style.fill = 'grey';
        //this.glow({ color: "#555", width: 10 });
        //document.getElementById('region-name').innerHTML = this.data('region');
        this.toFront();
        this.attr({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            fill: '#990000',
            stroke: '#fff',
                'stroke-width': '2'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The toFront() method isn't distorting anything.

Whats happening is that the underlying 'regions' are made like that, and its just that the other stuff overlaps it. If you remove the other stuff, you get something like...

[region jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sDDM/1/)

Do you actually want..

```
regions[i].mouseover(function (e) {...
```

Or have the hover over some other element ?

So its doing exactly what it should. If you don't want that to happen, you will need to either attach the handler not to a region, and instead the element you do want it to happen to. Or create a different region path that matches.

Comment: Thanks for replying , but I wanted somewhat like this http://jsfiddle.net/allankiezel/FJrNN/ . So what I need to do , change MY SVG or something ? Sorry I am not getting you cle4arly

Comment: Watch what happens when its just shrunk http://jsfiddle.net/3sDDM/2/ You will see the shape isn't what you think it is (assuming we are talking about the same thing!). You need to have a path with a fill for exactly the shape you want to make larger or whatever.

Comment: hmm so programatically I can't achieve this , I need to design the path :( or something ..

Comment: Yes, but if you are clever maybe parts of the path (borders) are already done (the other elements that cover it) that could be combined. Not trivial, but I imagine possible. Or maybe there are other free svg maps out there.

Comment: In fact Raphael has a getSubpath(from,to) method, so I wonder if you adjust find the neighbour and adjust from/to whether you could pretty much grab the border subpath from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57003/discussion-between-codingant-and-ian).

Comment: hey can you please explain me in brief